# Can I have a windows phone MyOEM account as independent individual?

Tags: microsoft-account, accounts

The following site offers a lot of debugging articles/tools and general insight to windows phones:
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/oem

Can anybody register and access OEM tools?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I started the process, however it seemed quite complicated and I felt better to ask about it to be sure.